# Azure to Ionos .org domain name transfer

Tags: azure, domain-name, domain-registrar

I want to transfer a custom domain I currently have on Azure, to Ionos. But after doing all the steps with the authentication code, I get an error some minutes later by email telling me this:

```
Dear xxxxx, 

The request to transfer the following domain name(s) to another registrar has been denied. The domain(s) currently has Private Registration: 

<website_name.com>

If you still want to transfer the domain(s) to another registrar, you must first cancel your Private Registration(s). 

Regards, 
Azure
```

There's nowhere I can find how to deactivate this Private Registration. How can I properly fully transfer my Azure custom domain to Ionos ? I can't find any good documentation about this.

On Azure, I'm on a basic support plan so I can't get any assistance upon my need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a panel "Privacy Settings" in the domains tab ([https://dcc.secureserver.net/control/{domain](https://dcc.secureserver.net/control/%7Bdomain) name}/settings)

This is what happened in my case:

- Privacy was on, so I put it off before switching domains.
- I received the same email asking to cancel the private registration
- Transfer failed
- Then I noticed a button was added to this panel (remove/cancel subscription, can't remember exactly).
- Disabled the subscription, and I had to put privacy off again.
- After that I got an email the transfer succeeded